# What steps to take to secure for G2 geomagnetic storm?

Tags: antenna, hf, propagation, equipment-protection, solar

So I see NASA has issued a [geomagnetic storm watch for a possible G2-level storm on the 11th](https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/news/g2-moderate-geomagnetic-storm-watch-issued-11-october-2021). I’m at about 53 degrees north geomagnetic latitude.

Is this something I need to care about equipment-wise? Should I disconnect my IC-7300 from the antenna to play it safe? And if I should disconnect it how do I determine when it is safe to hook it back up (and see what DX the storm may have opened up as it fades out)?

Comment: From memory: storms create/allow aurora, induce sub-1 Hz currents in 1000+ km wires and pipelines. Possibly small/large impact on HF propagation, which might be [interesting to observe](https://doi.org/10.1029/2018SW002008)

Comment: Geomagnetic storms are dangerous to satellites and power lines.  A typical antenna isn't large enough to collect enough power to be dangerous from this type of event.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing. A G2 storm is a common event; according to NOAA data it happens [an average of 600 times per 11-year sunspot cycle](https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/noaa-scales-explanation). It won't hurt your radio, but it might make HF communication a little more difficult. In fact, *no* category of storm is expected to hurt your radio in particular, although G4 and G5 storms can cause major radio blackouts, not to mention the other kind of blackout.